# Hierarchy Constraint Violation -- salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Salesforce has thrown a new error message at me, and so far I haven't found anything useful in the docs about this. I am trying to save an object in a controller extension, and it does in fact save the record, but instead of returning to the page that I indicate, it shows me the error message "Hierarchy Constraint Violation". In looking over the debug logs, this does not show up anywhere, despite the fact that I log as error any DML exceptions and re-throw them. I am not stifling any other exceptions, either.

I can't tell what this error even means, let alone where it is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turns out to be an attempt to create a self reference.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted so people will not spend time on the answered question? I wouldn't call it the worst platform, but I admit that turning on full debug on testing user saved my a$$ several times ;)